# iPhone iOS how to delete local files referenced from Core Data entity nested relationships when the entity is deleted?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a core data model defined as follows:

A User has many events. Each event can have many pictures. The relationships have "cascade" delete rule.

**I'm trying to understand how to delete local files when the entity disappears. Is there some kind of dealloc or "finalize" method that a core data entity calls before it is gone?**

Each picture entity has a reference to a local file that's stored in the app's documents directory.

When the user is deleted through table view's commitEditingStyle, I can delete the images by stepping through the relationships and delete the files manually:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    {
        // Delete the managed object for the given index path
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectStore] managedObjectContext];

        AppUser* managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        //clean up local files before deleting the object
        [self deleteLocalContentForAppUser:managedObject];        

//now delete the object
        [context deleteObject:managedObject];

        // Save the context to remember deletion
        NSError* error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            /*
             Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

             abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
             */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }

    }

}
```

**However, when the entities are deleted through other methods, and my fetched results controller gets notified of them, the nested relationships contain no objects.** The user's events set will not have any entities to step through and delete the local content. Is this the result of the "cascade" delete rule set for the relationship?

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
//    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
//     
    AppUser* managedObject = anObject;
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
//             [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            //             [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath] atIndexPath:newIndexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];


            //these methods cannot find any content to delete
            [managedObject deleteLocalImages];
            [managedObject deleteLocalContent];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath] atIndexPath:newIndexPath];

            [managedObject updateLocalImages];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement the `prepareForDeletion` method in your `NSManagedObject` subclass. It is invoked automatically before an object is deleted, so that you can also delete referenced files from there.